# HTML5 Canvas: Move directly to point

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

peoples.

Today I'm writing a game with canvas and I'm having an issue. I've made it so that when you click on the canvas, thew player move to the point you clicked on. The issue is, if the x is greater than y, the player will move all correctly until it gets to the end of the y value, then it turns and goes to the x point. I need it to go *directly* to the point where I click. Here's my code:

```
var canvas, ctx, fps;
canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
fps = 30;

window.onload = function(){init()}

function init(){
    setInterval(function(){
        draw();
    }, 1000 / fps);
}

var backgroundTile = new Image();
backgroundTile.src = "img/background.png";
var lighting = new Image();
lighting.src = "img/lighting.png"
var sprite = new Image();
sprite.src = "img/sprite.png";
var spritePos = {
    posX: 288,
    posY: 208
}
var goX, goY;
goX = spritePos.posX;
goY = spritePos.posY;

function update(){

    if (distance(spritePos.posX, spritePos.posY, goX, goY) <= 5){
        spritePos.posX = goX;
    }

    if (distance(spritePos.posX, spritePos.posY, goX, goY) <= 5){
        spritePos.posY = goY;
    }

    if(spritePos.posX > goX){
        if(spritePos.posX - goX > 5){
            spritePos.posX -= 5;
        } else {
            spritePos.posX = goX;
        }
    } else if(spritePos.posX < goX){
        if(goX - spritePos.posX > 5){
            spritePos.posX += 5;
        } else {
            spritePos.posX = goX;
        }
    }
    if(spritePos.posY > goY){
        if(spritePos.posY - goY > 5){
            spritePos.posY -= 5;    
        } else {
            spritePos.posY = goY;
        }
    } else if(spritePos.posY < goY){
        if(goY - spritePos.posY > 5){
            spritePos.posY += 5;
        } else {
            spritePos.posY = goY;
        }
    }
}

function drawSprite(){
    ctx.drawImage(sprite, spritePos.posX, spritePos.posY);
}

function drawLighting(){
    ctx.drawImage(lighting, (spritePos.posX - spritePos.posX) - 7, (spritePos.posY - spritePos.posY) - 7);
}

function drawBackground(){
    ctx.drawImage(backgroundTile, 0, 0);
}

$("#canvas").click(function(e){
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    goX = x - 32;
    goY = y - 32;
});

function draw(){
    clean();
    drawBackground();
    update();
    drawSprite();
    drawLighting();
}

function clean(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function distance(pnt1X, pnt1Y, pnt2X, pnt2Y){
    var xs = 0;
    var ys = 0;
    xs = pnt2X - pnt1X;
    xs = xs * xs;
    ys = pnt2Y - pnt1Y;
    ys = ys * ys;
    return Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(xs + ys));
}
```

I know this question is confusing, so if you need more info let me know.

Comment: See if this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038608/how-to-move-object-along-the-polygons/19038730#19038730

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware I'm not sure how to implement this in my code.

Comment: I added an answer with a modified example of this.

Comment: @PHPglue I know, I just wrote this tonight, it hasn't been cleaned up xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can implement a player moving directly to a point:

**[ONLINE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/kj69x/)**

(Updated with constant speed approach)

**Example:**

When we click somewhere on the canvas our "player" (a black square in this case) moves to the point.

```
var ctx = demo.getContext('2d'),
    x, y, x1, y1, x2 = 0, y2 = 0, /// positions
    f = 0,                        /// "progress"
    speed,                        /// speed based on dist/steps
    dist,                         /// distance between points
    steps = 3;                    /// steps (constant speed)

demo.onclick = function(e) {

    /// if we are moving, return
    if (f !== 0) return;

    /// set start point
    x1 = x2;
    y1 = y2;

    /// get and adjust mouse position    
    var rect = demo.getBoundingClientRect();
    x2 = e.clientX - rect.left,
    y2 = e.clientY - rect.top;

    /// calc distance
    var dx = x2 - x1,
        dy = y2 - y1;

    dist = Math.abs(Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy));

    /// speed will be number of steps / distance
    speed = steps / dist;

    /// move player
    loop();
}
```

Then in the loop the player will be moved from where it stopped last time to the point we click.

```
function loop() {

    /// clear current drawn player
    ctx.clearRect(x - 6, y - 6, 12, 12);

    /// move a step
    f += speed;

    /// calc current x/y position
    x = x1 + (x2 - x1) * f;
    y = y1 + (y2 - y1) * f;    

    /// at goal? if not, loop
    if (f < 1) {
        /// draw the "player"
        ctx.fillRect(x - 4, y - 4, 8, 8);

        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    } else {
        /// draw the "player"
        ctx.fillRect(x2 - 4, y2 - 4, 8, 8);

        /// reset f so we can click again
        f = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `onclick` with `onmousemove` to have a little fun.

Comment: Is there a way I could use this without using the f variable system? I want it to remain at a constant speed

Comment: This is a good idea of the concept you may want to use, although it does not center the rectangle, and sometimes passes the desired point when adjusting the time. I'm still voting this up based on concept. The rest you should be able to do some simple math on.

Comment: @JordanFitz for constant speed simply use trigonometry to calculate the distance between the points, then use that with number of steps (f.ex number of pixels you want it to move) to find the correct `speed` variable to use with `f`.

Comment: @JordanFitz please see updated answer and fiddle which shows how to get constant speed.

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware Thank you very much for your help. After some help from some other people, I was able to fix it using your method.